# Offset Range for arrays

Tags: excel, vba

so in regards of a previous question i am trying to get a hang on arrays but i dont quite understand them.

In this example, why cant i execute my with command? It gives me an error that an object is required

```
Dim aRng As Variant
aRng = Range("A4:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
aRng = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(aRng)

    'Copy Arng to Col C, and remove duplicates
    With aRng
        .Copy .Offset(, 2)
        .Offset(, 2).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        With aRng.Offset(, 2)
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) > 0 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    End With
End With
```

Comment: `aRng` is an array, not a `Range`... They are two different things.

Comment: `.copy` is not a member of a variant array.

Comment: ^ nor is `.Offset`, or `.Cells` or `.SpecialCells`...

Comment: what can i use as an alternative?

Comment: Just use a `Range`, I don't see why you need an array here: `Dim rng As Range`, `Set rng = Range("A4:A" ....)`, and drop the `.aRng = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(aRng)`.

Comment: @BigBen if you look at his last question, the use of Range is slowing the code down too much.  Hence the attempt at use variant arrays.

Comment: @ScottCraner - welp I should have read that.

Comment: Variant Arrays are not like Ranges on the worksheet.  They are stored in the memory and as such have no physical presence.  One would need to iterate the array and us a dictionary to create a list of unique items.  There are many examples on how to use a dictionary to do that sort of thing.

Comment: Or just write the array back to the sheet and then work with the new range on the sheet...

Comment: To answer your question, VBA is complaining that an "object is required" because an array isn't an object, and so a `With` block can't hold a reference to it. Remove the `With` block, and then bear in mind that `.Copy`, `.Offset`, `.SpecialCells` are all members of the `Range` class - an array doesn't have any members, it's just a structured bunch of values made easy to access using a subscript/index: `aRng(1, 1)` gets you the first value in that 2D variant array, and you use `For...Next` loops to iterate them: `If aRng(x, y) = vbNullString Then`.... consider renaming `aRng`, it's not a Range.

Comment: but if i still have to loop through the array, will it be any faster than my current code??

Comment: Looping through an array should be faster than looping through a range.